# Neo4j Enterprise 3.2 browser does not connect

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to learn Neo4j by using the trial Enterprise version, however the browser is not able to connect. The service is running but when I try to log in via browser http://localhost:7474/browser/ the error is:

> N/A: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your
>   web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j
>   Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the
>   root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being
>   unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network
>   problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is
>   configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use.
>   WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

In the console the error is:

```
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

I am using Chrome and the neo4j.conf is:

```
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

I understand from [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/511) the 3.2 version only allows bolt and I tried playing with the conf but so far no luck. Is there a way to get the local connection going with bolt?

Thank you in advance, Paola

Comment: Can you check the neo4j log ? Is there some errors ?

Comment: It is giving me a warning when I start the service, but it starts it ok. Then after I try to log in it gives no log:

2017-10-12 11:52:53.398+0000 WARN  You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 8, OpenJDK(TM) 8 or IBM J9.
2017-10-12 11:52:53.431+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.2.0 ========
2017-10-12 11:52:53.848+0000 INFO  Starting...
...
2017-10-12 11:53:02.374+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/

Comment: Humm, so the service is running, and the database is started. It looks good. And what happens if you use the `cypher-shell ` command (located into the `bin` folder of Neo4j) ? Are you able to connect to the database ?

Comment: The issue was solved with the new version, no issue appeared any more.